# Is there a way to format a dictionary, so that it behaves like a function depending on the key?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, tokenize

A user suggested that, for my tokenizer state machine, I define a dictionary keyed by state where each value is a dictionary keyed by an input to that state. I am struggling with second part, as I do not know how I would reformat my current function into a lookup table of inputs.

My original function:

```
def data_state(cur_codepoint:str, reconsume:bool):
    if reconsume == True: 
        codepoint = cur_codepoint 
    else:
        codepoint = consume_next_input_char()
    match codepoint:
        case '&':
                return_to(data_state, codepoint)
                switch_to_state('character_reference')
        case '<':
                switch_to_state('tag_open')
        case None:
                emit_token(EOF)
        case _:
                emit_token(codepoint)
```

Outline of pt.1:

```
States = { 
    'data': data,
    'rcdata': rcdata,
    #Remaining states
    #...
}
```

My attempt at pt.2:

```
data = {
    '&': ( return_to(data_state, codepoint), switch_to_state('character_reference') ),
    '<': switch_to_state('tag_open'),
    None: emit_token(EOF),
    _: emit_token(codepoint)
}
```

For some context, the state machine will receive one character/input at a time and I will have to perform operations based on what that char is. The tricky bit here is when I have to check if the input comes from a reconsume() function which asks that I consume the same char in a certain state - as opposed to the next input. I also do not know how to represent an anything else 'case _' in a dictionary nor how to call multiple functions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your existing code is a more obvious implementation. Using dictionaries in lieu of `case`/`match` statements was a thing we did in Python because there was no such statement, but that's no longer the case.

Comment: @larsks that being said, the case match statements are not supposed to be used in the way I'm using them, so how would you implement a dictionary in its place?

Comment: in dictionary you can keep only function's name without `()` and arguments and later you can get name and use `()` to run it. Eventually you can put with arguments using `lambda`.

Comment: if you need to execute two functions then put them in one function and execute this function or assign it in dictionary.

Comment: @furas I don't quite understand what you mean by the function's name without () and using lambda. As for executing executing multiple functions, that makes perfect sense, I will now implement that!

Comment: when you use `d = {"key": function()}` then you assign result from `function()`. You have to use `d = {"key": function}` without `()` and later use `()` to execute it `d["key"]()`

Comment: @furas does this work for python 3.0+ ?

Comment: it works on every Python. But this has one big problem if functions need to run with different arguments then you still have to use `if/else` to run them with different arguments. You would have to create functions which get all arguments - even if function doesn't use some values.

Comment: Could I simply reformat my current code, so that it uses IF ELSE instead of MATCH CASE and then it would be what you're explaining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this if/else statements are arguably more readable than the switch statements and switch statements in Python have no performance benefits. The dict approach may have performance benefits, but only for a large number of cases, and generally it is not very readable

But if you are committed to the dict approach then I would suggest 2 things:

1. For each case where multiple functions need to be called, write a new function that calls them and put that in the case dict
2. Deal with the wildcard case first:

- with an if/else statement that either calls the appropriate function directly and then skips the dict call
- or an if statement that changes your string to the appropriate key in your dict

As per your reply, here's the changing the string option:

```
def call_many_funcs():
    func_x(...)
    func_y(...)
    func_z(...)

cases = {
    'a': call_many_funcs,
    'b': some_func,
    'c': some_other_func,
    'not_found': not_found_func
    ...
}
```

Then to execute:

```
my_case = #whatever

if my_case not in cases.keys():
    my_case = 'not_found'

cases[my_case]()
```

Comment: I have roughly 55 states and so, 55 functions each like the one in my example (some vary drastically but the format still remains) - this means that I would have to create over 184 functions just to perform one task, then map these to keys in a dict, so I think another method would be better.

Comment: Pt.2 As for the wildcard part and assuming I stuck to using one single dictionary value for each state, how would you suggest I tackle it? I have one rough idea. I realised that I can simply assign a fake value - not used in any cases. E.g. I use an IF statement to check if the char is in that state, if it is then I return state[char] else I can assign the value to a unique char like '.' and then feed it back into the state and it matches and does whatever.

Comment: Ive edited to reflect your additional responses

Comment: Perfect. In my code I'll be using '.' instead of 'not_found' because characters and most special symbols usually match to something.